# S3 as a target group on ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-application-load-balancer

I used to be a GCP engineer. The Global Load Balancer of GCP can route to S3 via sub-paths. For example /hello will route to a bucket named `hello`.

Does AWS Load Balancer have the same feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS load balancers do not currently have this feature. AWS users generally use CloudFront to route different sub-paths to different backends, like different S3 buckets.

Comment: Oh, I did not know that cloudfront has such a feature. Can it be set in origins tab of Cloudfront?

Comment: Yes, it is literally the origins setting that you would use to accomplish this. You can configure different origins to serve different paths.